# What is the relevance of 'en_AU' in 'LC_CTYPE'? and what is `locale LC_CTYPE` output all about?

Tags: locale

First off: Although I can understand the relevance of geographic-region detail for LC_TIME, LC_NUMERIC, and most other LC_* vars, I don't quite see how 'en_AU' relates to LC_CTYPE...
Isn't UTF-8 (and other encodings) enough of a definition in themselves (for LC_CTYPE), as and *encoding* by definiton is consistant?...

Thinking about it as I write, it may be that different regions of the world capitalize their lower-case letters differently...  If this is the case, how does `iconv` handle this?..
This `iconv` point is actually what started me on this line of thought, becaue it doesn't ask for a locale, it only asks for the input encoding format.

My next puzzle is: What do the line-items in the output from `locale LC_CTYPE` refer to, and/or where is a good place to get a layout... Perhaps a more relevant question is: By whom, and where, would this info be needed? ..
I'm pretty sure I don't need it... but it all help to fill in the picture of 'scripts' and 'encodings' and 'locales'; which is surprisingly *non-trivial* as soon as you leave the *world of ASCII*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the locale variables use the same locale name so that you can specify your favorite locale in a single swoop, e.g. `LANG=en_AU.utf8`. As you surmise, the country information is occasionally relevant even in `LC_CTYPE`, e.g. the uppercase version of `i` is `I` in most languages but `İ` in Turkish (`tr_TR.utf8`). But don't expect miracles; for example the lowercase-uppercase correspondence is one-to-one, so there's no good uppercase version of `ß` in `de_DE.iso8859-1` (it should be `SS`).

You'll have an easier time understanding the output of `locale -k LC_CTYPE`, with `-k` to see the keyword names in addition to the values (without `-k`, the output format is designed so you can get the value of a specific keyword, e.g. `locale ctype-width`). The list of keywords and their meanings is system-dependent, as is the way locale data is stored, and doesn't interest many people, so you may not find much documentation outside the source code of your C library. By far the most useful form of the locale command is `locale -a` to list available locale names.

For [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (i.e. non-embedded Linux):

- All locale data other than messages is stored in `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive`. This file is generated by [`localedef`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/localedef.html) from data in `/usr/share/i18n` and `/usr/local/share/i18n`. The format of the locale definition files in `/usr/share/i18n/locales` is only documented in the source code, I think.
- The format of the character set and encoding definition files in `/usr/share/i18n/charmaps` is [standardized by POSIX:2001](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap06.html#tag_06_04). These files (or, in [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Generic-Charset-Conversion.html), the compiled version in `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive`) are used by the [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) [programming](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/iconv.html) and [commmand line](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/iconv.html) facility. Encoding conversions also rely on code in `/usr/lib/gconv/*.so`. The Gnu libc manual documents [how to write your own gconv module](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/glibc-iconv-Implementation.html), though that section contains the text “This information should be sufficient to write new modules. Anybody doing so should also take a look at the available source code in the GNU C library sources.”.
- Message catalogs get special treatment because each application comes with its own set. Message catalogs live in `/usr/share/locale/*/LC_MESSAGES`. The manual contains [documentation for application writers](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Message-Translation.html). GNU libc supports both the [POSIX interface `catgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/catgets.html) and the more powerful [gettext interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext).

Written languages are indeed very complicated, even if you don't stray far from English. Are the French and German `ü` the same character (is a [“tréma”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trema_%28diacritic%29#French) exactly the same as an [“umlaut”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trema_%28diacritic%29#Umlaut), and does it matter that French and German printers typeset the accent at a slightly different height)? What is the uppercase of `i` (it's `İ` in Turkish)? Does `Ö` transliterate to `O` if you only have ASCII (in German, it's `OE`)? Where is `Ä` sorted in a dictionary (in Swedish, it's after `Z`)? And that's just a few examples with European languages written in the latin alphabet! The [Unicode mailing list](http://unicode.org/consortium/distlist.html) has a lot of examples and sometimes heated discussions on such topics.

Comment: thanks :).. understood.. `locale` does it's best in very difficult terrain, and anyone dealing with a fringe case would (hopefully) be aware of the quirks involved and make special concessions... The `locale ctype-width` example solved my real-world problem of how to generically get `iconv` to print out the Unicode Codepoint of a particular char based on the current locale (for the Multi-Lingual-Plane..UTF-16 surrogates as usual being *the fly in the ointment* ).. I think(?) this should do the trick: `echo -n "∴" |iconv -f "$(locale charmap)" -t "UTF-16BE" |xxd -p` ... 2234

Comment: I've just noticed, that `en_AU` (in `en_AU.UTF-8`) etc, appears to be just a name.. It is the name of a file which defines that particular "whatever-name-you-like" locale... but that now makes me wonder where the `.UTF-8` suffix comes from, because all the LC_* vars are defined in this file... Perhaps `locale` gets all its info from this file, either directly or indirectly, and just tacks on the '.UTF-8` suffix, but I can't see any reference to UTF-8.. These definition files are in `/usr/share/i18n/locales"

Comment: @fred.bear: Try `strace date` and other commands to see what files are actually used. Most locale information is compiled and not read from `/usr/share/i18n/locales` under normal operation. See my edit.

Comment: thanks again... I think this may explain to some degree where the `.UTF-8` suffix comes from... I just changed my default `date` by modifying `/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_AU`... using this command: `sudo localedef -f UTF-8 -i en_AU_mod  fred` ... The default output of `date` is now `[2011-04-27][11.21.44]` and the output from `locale |grep LC_TIME` is: **LC_TIME=fred** ... :)